# Playing video in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-videoview

I need to place a video in a Xamarin Forms. I have read several tutorials but I always get stuck in the first step, calling

```
VideoViewRenderer.Init()
```

VideoViewRenderer does not exist anywhere.

I have added:

```
using MediaManager;
```

And, by using NuGet, I installed Plugin.MediaManager and Plugin.MediaManager.Forms.

Plugin.MediaManager and Plugin.MediaManager.Forms versions are 0.7.1

What is missing?

Thanks

Jaime

Comment: `VideoViewRenderer` exists at the native level on each supported platform, i.e. on Android it is `MediaManager.Forms.Platforms.Android.VideoViewRenderer.Init()` (  https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager/search?q=VideoViewRenderer&unscoped_q=VideoViewRenderer) Review the sample app: https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager/blob/develop/Samples/ElementPlayer.Forms.Android/MainActivity.cs

Comment: @SushiHangover MediaManager.Forms namespace only contains Xaml namespace...Platforms namespace is missing.My version is last version: 0.7.1

Comment: are you doing this in your platform projects or your shared project?

Comment: @Jason platform project... in MainActivity.... I have read that I should use CrossMediaManager.Current.Init() instead, but in my case, error shown in https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager/issues/437 but no solution